# JAVAFX: load exception for an FXML file

Tags: java, javafx

I already searched for a solution in preview posts, but I didn't find it. I'm using javafx for some time but without the use of fxml. Now my project is getting big and I'm regretting not having used fxml before. I'm doing some test but I don't be able to run my application. The structure of my project is the following:

```
src|
    JavaFiles|
        GUIManagement| GUIManagement.java
        main.java
    Resources|
        CSS|
        FXML|MainGUI.fxml
```

In the following my example code:
main.java:

```
public class MainManagement {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUIManagement guiApp = new GUIManagement();
        guiApp.runGUI();
    }
}
```

GUIManagement.java:

```
public class GUIManagement extends Application implements Initializable {

    // GRAPHICS ELEMENTS
    @FXML private Button btnSideBoard;
    @FXML private Button btnShoppingList;
    @FXML private Button btnStatistics;

    public void runGUI() {
        Application.launch();
    }

    @FXML
    private void test() {
        System.out.println("Click");
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        AnchorPane root = 
            FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../../Resources/FXMLFiles/MainGUI.fxml"));
        Scene newScene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(newScene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        btnStatistics.setText("Cambio");
    }
}
```

MainGUI.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import java.net.URL?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="JavaFiles.GUIManagement.MainMenuGUI">
   <children>
      <VBox id="verticalPane" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="174.0" layoutY="8.0" prefHeight="486.0" prefWidth="251.0" styleClass="background">
         <children>
            <Label id="title" text="Shop" />
            <Button fx:id="btnSideBoard" mnemonicParsing="false" styleClass="mainButton" text="Sideboard" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" styleClass="mainButton" text="Shopping List" />
            <Button disable="true" mnemonicParsing="false" styleClass="mainButton" stylesheets="@../CSS/CSS_generic_setup.css" text="Statistics" />
         </children>
         <stylesheets>
            <URL value="@../CSS/CSS_generic_setup.css" />
            <URL value="@../CSS/CSS_main_menu.css" />
         </stylesheets>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Finally, the error that I obtain is:

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/Projects/StuffManagement/out/production/StuffManagement/Resources/FXMLFiles/MainGUI.fxml:9

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:932)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at JavaFiles.GUIManagement.GUIManagement.start(GUIManagement.java:37)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: JavaFiles.GUIManagement.MainMenuGUI
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:927)
... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: JavaFiles.GUIManagement.MainMenuGUI.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
... 24 more
```

Someone can help me to solve this problem?
Thank you very much,

Marco

Comment: I'm still new to JavaFX, but are you sure that there is a `launch()` method that take no parameters?

Comment: The issue is with your controller, which you haven’t posted. It is either not public, or it doesn’t have a public no-argument constructor.

Comment: Look at what @James_D has to say about `..` in the duplicate answe.

Comment: The resource names are incorrect but that is not what is causing the exception posted in the question

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: You ahve `fx:controller="JavaFiles.GUIManagement.MainMenuGUI"` in the FXML file and `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: JavaFiles.GUIManagement.MainMenuGUI.<init>()` as the error. It's telling you that your controller class does not have a no-arg constructor. Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score -2):

Remove "Use fx:root construct" in the SceneBuilder.
This throws the javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601) exception

Comment: This is completely incorrect, as you can see by looking at either the FXML or the stack trace.